# What is a good higher-voltage alternative to the TI TPS2113A power mux?

Tags: power-supply, power

UPDATE: According to the TI datasheet, 6V is absolute max, so I guess I'm ok.

Board: https://www.pololu.com/product/2596

Datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2113a.pdf

NOTE: I'm looking for a breakout board, not a SMD.

I'm building a project that runs on a 5V wall-wart, or if during a power outage, it switches to 4-D cells at 6V. It draws about 1 A of current for 15 seconds per day, otherwise it sips about 50 uA in normal operation.

I bought a TPS2113A breakout from Pololu and was excited to use it, but completely ignored the fact that the max input rating is 5.5V. I don't want to use a power-hungry LM7805 LDO to reduce the voltage, but I haven't found a suitable power mux that can deliver up to 2A. (I also don't want to overdrive it, but maybe that's OK.)

Everything else in my project is OK with 6V.

This seems like a common problem (4x1.5V backup + 5V PSU). Any suggestions? (Besides another SMPS, LDO, Zener, or voltage divider... or are those good ideas?)

Comment: Peter, I guess I'm missing something important in reading you. All you appear to need is about 90 Joules per day (perfect efficiency assumed for discussion purposes only.) Even on a bad day and under high load, D cell alkalines will deliver perhaps 30 kJ each. (And that's assuming the worst and then some.) Multiply that by four and you have 120 kJ. That's more than 3.5 years! Why do you care about the wall-wart?? What's the point? Even if you insisted on at least 5 V being present and without any fancy ICs to boost/buck, you'd still get over a year out of them.

Comment: @jonk You missed the part about the 1 Amp. It has to drive a 24V motor a few times, and the 5->24V boost circuit draws 1 A.

Comment: Are you saying that it draws 1 A from the 5 V source to produce 24 V (which I don't see written down in your question?) Or are you saying that you need 24 V at 1 A and that much, much more current is drawn from the 5 V to produce that?

Comment: It is in the fifth paragraph. 1A is drawn from the 5V source to produce 24V at enough current to drive a motor.

Comment: I see "24" in your comments. But my browser cannot find "24" in your question. Regardless, I take your point. Your situation requires a voltage boost for a short time. None of that really impacts the important part of my comment -- except that you probably do need a "fancy IC" that I had originally imagined you could avoid. I still want to know why you care about the wall-wart. It doesn't seem to be needed, at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic solution is using a wired-OR connection, but to replace D1 and D2 with two *ideal diodes* chips. Unfortunately, your battery voltage is higher than the line power, the battery will always be on, and this solution is unusable.

[image: Diode-OR]

Since you want to avoid SMD parts, You have to find an alternative power mux module with a breakout board, but there aren't many, it seems.

Or you can try designing a discrete solution similar to an ideal diode/power mux. The idea is to use a LDO to power an ultra low-power comparator, which in turns switching a logic-level MOSFET before its own power runs out. The reference voltage can be derived from the LDO simultaneously. Both inputs of the comparator are scaled down with a resistive divider. Here's an example, it needs some modifications before it's usable.

[image: Comparator-MOSFET-OR]

However, the most sensible solution to me, is still using a SOIC power mux chip and solder it on a breakout board.

Another solution is simply to keep using your power mux, and add a buck-boost converter to your battery to maintain a constant voltage of 5 V. Buck-boost is extremely common in the commercial market, you can just [search for buck-boost converter controller chips](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?k=Buck-Boost) at an electronics supplier's website, such as Mouser and Digikey. If you need a breakout board, simply search "buck-boost breakout board". Just for starter, Sparkfun has a [TI TPS63070-based breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15208). It comes with an efficiency penalty, but perhaps it's already adequate - A SMPS is 80%+ efficient under full load, and it enters a powersave mode when there's no load, only consumes power at a level of 100 uA, and it can always be disabled to save more power if line-power is available.

Comment: Right, but it is always running. I don't want to draw current off the batteries just to get them down to 5V, otherwise they'll just die over time.

Comment: @PeterT  On second thought, I think using a SMPS is the easiest solution (you want a module, and there are a lot of SMPS modules, but power mux? Not many, I think), although it comes with an efficiency penalty, but perhaps it's better than you think. First, buck-boost converters are already 80% efficient under fully load. Also, most converters automatically enter a powersave mode when there's no load, drawing very low current, TI TPS63070 has a quiescent current in the 100 uA range. Finally, you can always disable the converter when it's running on line-power.

Comment: thanks for the schematics! that first solution is simple. my biggest problem is (a) not killing the batteries with an boost converter that is always on, and (b) I still need to draw significant current through the circuit (1A) for a few brief periods during the day. I have several buck/boosts that I will try and measure current today. Then I will try to source a low power comparitor and an LDO and see if I can build your circuit. Thank you for the suggestion... i don't think there is a premade solution out there.

Comment: @PeterT  Another question: what is the lowest voltage that your circuit can be operated at? Voltage drop can be a problem. The most problematic/unlucky scenario is when the line power is lost when the motor is running, it can create all types of problems.

Comment: (or 比尔盖子) ... 4.0V. Below that, a primary component of the circuit (a 5V to 24V 1A boost converter) drops below 17V and the motors fail to turn. That's the limiter on battery life, too (est. 15 days based on Duracell's discharge curves at 1000mA on their website). The firmware has a safety monitor: and if the motor fails to actuate after a certain # of tries, the MCU goes into an error loop. (The motor isn't protected from burning out, unfortunately, but hopefully this safety catch works!) i have enough cap to prevent reboots due to di/dt from the motor... at least in my testing!

Comment: (比尔盖子) ... What if I used TWO buck/boosts: one on the wall wart and one on the battery pack, and then used your ideal diode circuit? Why do you mean by ideal diode chip? Is that a single slice of silicon with two diodes that have the same forward voltage drop? thanks!

Comment: @PeterT Aha! I think you've found a good solution. I'll update my answer to explain your question, I'll ping you later.

Comment: @PeterT On second thought, using a boost converter may be a quick solution, still, the fundamental limintation of a diode-OR circuit is that the "preferred" power supply must have a significant voltage higher than the "backup" source, in this case, it means the voltage will be as high as 6.5 V, and I don't think 6.5 V is acceptable for your circuit. Ultimately, MOSFET + comparator is the solution to go if you want no SMD. BTW, not using/soldering SMD parts is a serious limitation, most SMD parts do not have breakout board, and really, an SOIC is not difficult to solder to an adapter board.